# How to understand the usage of "so that" in this context?

Tags: sentence-meaning, phrase-usage

> The lake froze solid and the Weasley twins were punished for bewitching several snowballs **so that** they followed Quirrell around, bouncing off the back of his turban.

I'm confused by the usage of "**so that**" in this sentence. "*So that*" usually means "*in order that*", but "**bewitching several snowballs**" is unnecessary for them to follow Quirrell around. In other words, they don't really have to bewitch snowballs in order to follow Quirrell around. Anyway, I may simply misunderstand what the whole sentence is trying to convey. Can someone help me to understand it?

--excerpted from Harry Potter.

Comment: It can mean "I order that" in purpose adjuncts, but here it introduces a result adjunct. "Think of "so that" as meaning "with the result that".

Comment: Correction of typo: "**In** order that"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the magic snowballs that follow Quirrell around, not the twins.  They bewitched the snowball to give those snowballs the power to follow Quirrell and to bounce off his turban.

Comment: Oh! That 'they' refers to snowballs, not Weasleys! Thank you!

Comment: May I know if it's easy for you to identify what 'they' refers to in that sentence? I have read it many times and still failed to figure that out.

Comment: it is easy, the twins are unlikely to be bouncing off a turban, and don't need to be bewitched to follow, so they must be something else.  I would never be confused. I  fact it took me a couple of readings of your question to understand what your problem was. I would never have guessed that anyone would think that "they" could be the twins in this context.

Comment: I guess that's the convention between two languages are different.

Comment: @dan Once you read **they**, read the sentence in reverse until you encounter a noun. The first noun you'll see is **snowballs**. In *general* (although not always), a pronoun refers to the noun closest to it.

Comment: @JasonBassford that's helpful! Noted.

Comment: @dan:  I realize this is *Harry Potter*, whose world is one where some of the constraints upon reality have been relaxed, but do you really think the twins could be bouncing off a turban?   Perhaps the meaning of **bouncing off** is unclear to you?  It is not a transitive verb there.  When you throw a rubber ball against a wall, the ball "bounces off" the wall.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Yes, I'm also confused about "bouncing off" originally.

Comment: @dan Well, that explains it.  The snowballs  *carom* off the turban. The balls "rebound".